# Is there easy way to match word from a database table field with soundex?

Tags: php, mysql, soundex

Hi Just Before going deep into soundex, wanted to ask quick qiestion.

1 - field in the table[title] contains a "Sentence that has WORD I am looking for"

Q - Is there are easy way to match the WORD using a sundex ?

Comment: Do you understand what *soundex* does?

Comment: Gee I told above just before deep into it. it is an algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SOUNDEX` is a way to match `Smith`, `Smythe` and `Smeathe` while searching for `Smith`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    names
WHERE   name_soundex = SOUNDEX('Smith')

name     name_soundex
--
Smith    S530
Smythe   S530
Smeathe  S530
```

What you need is called `FULLTEXT` indexing:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_mytable_title ON mytable (title)

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+fox')

title
--
A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Thanks. That is definitely helpful, As I believe soundex is for matching a standalone word, but not finding out in the context and matching, right?